# How to API design architecture for long delay process

Tags: web-development, api-design, django

Im trying to start an API design using Django Rest Framework, and the problem Im trying to solve is the following:
Request endpoint is like this:
POST
http://server:8080/api/v1/device
attribute: create

When my server receives this API request, it will launch a backend process which takes around 20-60 seconds(Starts an SSH connection to a remote server and check periodically for status there.). I'm not sure how to respond to initial API request? Using  a 200 OK indication that request is handled with a "starting" and then offer an endpoint to provide status?

What is the best architecture for this type of requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server blocks and responds only when the work is finished, HTTP 200 is indeed the way to go. Make sure you document the waiting time, since some clients may have shorter timeouts (and customers awaiting the reply may consider that something wrong happened).

Otherwise, you may return immediately, in which case HTTP 202 is the correct code:

> HTTP 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.

<sup>*Source: [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)*</sup>

Remark: instead of (or additionally to) making the endpoint which provides status, you may also consider [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets). This *may* reduce the bandwidth by freeing the client from sending repetitive requests for status: instead, the server will push to the client a notification when the process finishes.